# Why was this migrated to StackOverflow?

Tags: support, migration

I believe that [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49110/11849) belongs on CV since it is not a question on how to write code, but the error probably results from the specified model. Why was it migrated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My error; I'll reopen it here, SO copy should be closed soon.